# Concatenating two AJAX variables or HTML classes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am having issues concatenating two AJAX variables using JQuery and PHP to insert into DB (MySQL)... Here is the code:

```
$.ajax({
      url: DIR+"some.php",
      method: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: {
        mobile: mobile.val(),
        dialcode: dialcode.val();
        mobilenumber: mobilenumber.val('dialcode'+'mobile'); // This seems to be the error here
      },
```

The PHP as follows:

```
     <?php
  session_start();
  if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == "xmlhttprequest") {

    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = preg_replace("#[<> ]#i", "", $_POST['username']);
    $mobilenumber = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#i", "", $_POST['dialcode'.'mobile']);
    $gender = preg_replace("#[<> ]#i", "", $_POST['gender']);
    $country = preg_replace("#[<> ]#i", "", $_POST['country']);

    $session = $_SESSION['id'];

    $m=$edit->saveEditing( $mobile, $mobilenumber, $gender, $country);
     $array = array("msg" => $m);
    echo json_encode($array);
    }

?>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here...I am getting :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; /locahost/pub/js/file.js:8" please
>   find the error comment note in the js above to locate the reference

I basically need the `dialcode` and `mobile` to be concatenated and inserted as once value into the DB as `mobilenumber`

Comment: Why can't you simply send the 2 and combine them server side?

Comment: Replace ; with ,

Comment: @charlietfl how can I go about combining them server side? That sounds like it could work.

Comment: Simple concatenation ... `$mobilenumber = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#i", "", $_POST['dialcode'] . $_POST['mobile']);`

Answer (score 1):

The error is on your question:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; /locahost/pub/js/file.js:8

This means that, on `line 8` of your `file.js` you have an unexpected `;`

```
6>    data: {
7>        mobile: mobile.val(),
8>        dialcode: dialcode.val(); // Here, you are using ; instead of ,
9>        mobilenumber: mobilenumber.val('dialcode'+'mobile'); // Here too!
10>   },
```

JS Object properties should be separated with `,`, not with `;`.

---

Also your line where you concatenate two strings is strange, since in jQuery, if you pass any attributes to the `val()` function, you are SETTING the input value, not reading as you want.

If I understood, you want to merge dialcode and mobile in a single field to send to php, right?

If so, you need to do:

```
mobilenumber: dialcode.val() + mobile.val(),
```

---

Some tips to you that are starting now:

- Errors are not monsters, they are your guide, and most of them show directly where your error is. **Read them!**
- Use a GOOD IDE, if you are programming in web, including PHP, I recommend strongly PHPStorm, it's heavy, but will be your best friend forever! S2 That's because a good IDE will highlight all your syntax errors, and have many and many features that you will love as you known them.

Comment: Much better than the other *"try this"* answers

Comment: It seems even the replacement of <code>;</code> to <code>,</code> still doesn't work. It still doesn't seem to send the data to the db, what could I be missing?